# Random selection based off of floating point weight

Tags: php, random

Let's say I have an array with the following values:

```
0.7523262
0.9232192
1.5824928
5.2362123
```

What is the best way to randomly pick a value from this array so that the higher the value, the more likely it is to be selected? There are common functions to make a weighted selection, but they all use mt_rand(), which wouldn't work for something like this.

For example, a value of 2.4652474 would be twice as likely to be picked as a value of 1.2326237.

Comment: How can the pick be random if it's also weighted?  Do you have a specific algorithm in mind (in plain english) for how you will do the weighting?

Comment: Does it matter 'how' they are more likely? Should there be a linear increasing chance by position (lowest, 2nd lowest etc) (this is probably easy), or an increasing chance linear to the actual content, some other way (like non-linear) they relate? Doesn't matter if they relate at all, but just increase in chance?

Comment: @Calvin, what do you not understand about my question? I read through it again and it appears to be in plain english to me. I want to pick a number at random from the list, but the higher the number, the more likely it is to be picked.

Comment: wel.. you did add the explanation about how they should be related after his comment, so that might be it?

Comment: Yep, you added explanation after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best way, but you can accomplish what you describe by calculating the sum of all entries in the array, multiplying that by a random number between zero and one to get the target, and then calculating a running total for all entries in the array until that total exceeds the target. Return the entry that exceeded the target.

Answer (score 1):

Compute a random number between `0` and the sum of the entire array.

Sort the array, so that lower numbers comes first.

Start summing up the array, from the left. When the sum is above the random number, you choose the index you have reached.

If you e.g. have

```
Array = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5]
Sum of Array = 7
Random = 4
```

We check the first index. This is below `4`, so we would add the second number `1 + 1.5 = 2.5`, this is not above `4` so we add another number `2.5 + 2 = 4.5` which is above `4` so we choose the third index.

Comment: I think you're right. I think I had a plan by sorting, but I can't remember of it now.